# Crack sha256 when you know the pass form

Tags: sha256

Is it possible to write a code that can crack the `sha256` hash when you know the form of password? For example the password form is `*-**********` which is 12-13 characters long and:

1. The first char is one number from 1 to 25
2. Second one is hyphen
3. In each char from the third one to the end, you can put `a...z`, `A...Z` and `0...9`

After guessing each pass, code converts the pass to `sha256` and see whether the result hash is equal to our hash or not and then print the correct pass.

I know all possible numbers is a big number `(26+26+10)^10` but I want to know that:

1. Is it possible to write such code?
2. If yes, is it possible to run whole code in less than one day (because I think it takes a lot of time to complete the whole code)?
3. Since I can't ask you to write a code for me, how and where can I ask for this code?

Comment: don't try breaking satoshimines.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "crack" a SHA256 hash no matter how much information you know about the plaintext (assuming by crack you mean derive the plaintext from the hash). Even if you knew the password you could not determine any procedure for reversing the hash. In technical terms, there is no known way to perform a [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) on a SHA256 hash.

That means you have to resort to guessing or brute forcing the password:

You have a prefix, which can be any value in `[1-25]-` and 10 additional characters in `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. That means the total number of possible passwords is: `25 * 62^10` or `20,982,484,146,708,505,600`.

If you were able to compute and check a billion passwords per second it would take you `20,982,484,146` seconds to generate every possible hash. If you start now you'll be finished in about 665 years.

If you are able to leverage some more computing power and generate a trillion hashes per second it would only take a bit more than half a year. The good news is that computing hashes can be done in parallel, so it is easy to utilize multiple machines. The bad news is that kind of computing power isn't going to be cheap.

To answer your questions:

1. *Is it possible to write such code?* It is possible to write a program that will iterate over the entire range of possible passwords and check it against the hash(es) you want to determine the plaintext for.
2. *If yes, is it possible to run whole code in less than one day.* Yes, if you can compute and check around `10^15` hashes per second.
3. *How and where can I ask for this code?* This is the least of your problems.

Fortunately, since bitcoin uses sha256, it is pretty easy to find rough numbers on the amount of computing power it takes to generate the number of hashes you need.

If the numbers in [this article](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7501/how-much-does-it-cost-in-computing-time-hardware-to-mine-bitcoins) are correct a Raspberry Pi can generate `2*10^5` hashes per second. I believe the newer Raspberry Pis are more powerful than that so I'm going to double that to `4*10^5`. You need to generate about `10^15` hashes per second to be done in less than a day.

You're going to need `250,000,000` Raspberry Pis.